# How can I check if a Perl variable is in PDL format (i.e. is a piddle)?

Tags: perl, pdl

I'm using [PDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL). If I am given variable `$foo` that can be a hash reference, an array reference, a scalar, or a piddle (which can be empty or null), how can I tell if it's a piddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical way to check if something is of a certain class is with [`isa`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html#DESCRIPTION).

```
if( $thing->isa("PDL") ) { ... }
```

This respects [inheritance](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/PDL/Basic/Pod/Objects.pod#Inheritance). So long as `$thing` is a subclass of PDL (or says it is) the above will work. This protects you both against custom subclasses and changes to PDL itself. Below is an example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

package MyPDL;
our @ISA = qw(PDL);

package main;

use PDL;
use Scalar::Util qw(blessed);

my $stuff = pdl [1..10];

say blessed $stuff;                                   # PDL
say "\$stuff is a PDL thing" if $stuff->isa("PDL");   # true

my $bar = MyPDL->new([1..10]);
say blessed $bar;                                     # MyPDL
say "\$bar is a PDL thing" if $bar->isa("PDL");       # true
```

However, method calls don't work on non-references and unblessed references; you'll get an error if you try. You can work around this in two ways. First is to use [`eval BLOCK`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) to trap the error, like `try` in another language.

```
if( eval { $thing->isa("PDL") } ) { ... }
```

If `$thing` is not an object, `eval` will trap the error and return false. If `$thing` is an object, it will call `isa` on it and return the result.

The downside is this will trap *any* error, including an error from `isa`. Rare, but it happens. To avoid that, use [Scalar::Util's blessed()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#blessed) to first determine if `$thing` is an object.

```
use Scalar::Util qw(blessed):

if( blessed $thing && $thing->isa("PDL") ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) to find out if a variable is:

- an object (using the `blessed` function)
- a reference, and if so, what type of reference (using the `reftype` function)

You can use the [`isa`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html#$obj-%3Eisa%28-TYPE-%29) method to find out whether an object is an instance of a particular class or inherits from that class.

Piddles are simply PDL objects, i.e. things that have been blessed into the `PDL` class, so

```
$foo->isa('PDL')
```

will return true if `$foo` is a piddle.

All together:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use PDL;
use Scalar::Util qw(blessed reftype);

my $scalar   = 19;
my $arrayref = [ qw(foo bar) ];
my $hashref  = { baz => 'qux' };
my $piddle   = pdl [ 1..10 ];

foreach my $item ($scalar, $arrayref, $hashref, $piddle) {
    my $reftype;

    if ( defined(blessed($item)) ) {
        say 'piddle' if $item->isa('PDL');
    }
    elsif ( defined($reftype = reftype($item)) ) {
        say $reftype;
    }
    else {
        say 'Not a reference';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Not a reference
ARRAY
HASH
piddle
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it's used `isa` to respect inheritance rather than `reftype`.

Comment: Yes, I should have said `blessed`. I didn't even know `blessed` returned the type.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks, fixed. Now I feel like my answer is just a rip-off of yours :-/

Comment: I'm fine with saying the same thing two different ways.